# cpanel - When add database didn't show in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I'm working to upload my website in my hosting. I upload code successfully but when I create database name and assign user to it 
Then go to phpmyadmin I didn't show database name that I added or any database name

Any body know why not appear?

Answer (score 0):

If you have WHM root access then please give a try with WHM Home » SQL Services » Database Map Tool

If you do not have root access then you will have to contact your hosting provider to check the cPanel logs of this issues.

Answer (score 0):

You left out a couple of details about how you created the database (maybe your host uses cPanel or some custom solution), whether you're permitted to have more than one database, and whether you have more than one account to access the database, but we can guess at the source of the problem anyway.

Most likely, and most commonly, you're not connected through phpMyAdmin using the same user account you used to create the database. MySQL (by default) allows an anonymous user to connect, and if you have multiple accounts -- which often means having the same username and password but different "host" setting -- those accounts can have different permissions; so if you connect from a different host that can affect your permissions.

Check the username, password, and host from which you're using whatever other tool you used to create the database, then compare them to what you're using in phpMyAdmin. Pay particular attention to the host from which you're connecting, some web hosts will do something like run the standard management tools (such as cPanel or their custom solution) on a different host than your webserver, so when you try to access phpMyAdmin it's a different host.

You should simply ask your host for assistance. They'll be able to provide you with the proper authentication settings to connect.